# BitmapImage to Byte[] in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, byte, buffer, bitmapimage

```
Private Function BufferFromImage(imageSource As BitmapImage) As Byte()
    If Not IsNothing(imageSource) Then
        Dim encoder As New BmpBitmapEncoder
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(imageSource))

        Using ms As New MemoryStream
            encoder.Save(ms)
            Return ms.GetBuffer
        End Using
    End If

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

That function takes a long processing speed.
 I want a faster process. What should I do?

(Not WindowsPhone. Used WPF VB.net)

Comment: Do you want to get just the raw pixel data, or does it have to be an encoded buffer, like you have now?

Answer (score -2):

To convert to a byte[] you can use a MemoryStream:

```
byte[] data;
JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapImage));
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
 {
  encoder.Save(ms);
  data = ms.ToArray();
 }
```